# What MOSS issues can I expect with default SQL Server collation?

Tags: sql-server

SharePoint installation guidance specifies that SQL Server collation should be set to Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS (case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, Kana-sensitive, and width-sensitive).  However, our internal hosting group uses the default SQL Server collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  What are the potential issues we might face with MOSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server collation must be configured for case-insensitive, which is ok in your case.

If you use SharePoint itself to create its different databases, it will set the required collation automatically. However, if you use precreated databases - make sure you to change the collation manually. Otherwise, SharePoint won't even let you use those databases.

Answer (score 1):

Will they actually change the collation?  If SharePoint is creating the databases it will set the collation and override the server defaults.  This was my experience in a previous environment with SharePoint using a large shared SQL Ent server.